# How to search something on NSMutableArray

Tags: search, nsmutablearray, ios7.1

I have an NSMutable array like this

`

```
mutablearray
{
 "colour_id" = 1,
  "day_id" =  "2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"
},

{
 "colour_id" = 2,
  "day_id" =  "2011-05-06 00:00:00 +0000"
},
```

`

I want to search whether `2011-05-06 00:00:00 +0000` this particular date is available or not in the `NSMutableArray`. How can I perform the search for this in ios. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of doing it is to convert each `day_id` value into an `NSDate` object and call `[NSDate compare]` to see if it's equal, however you can cheat and simply compare the strings, if you are sure they will always appear in this format:

```
NSArray *yourArray = ...;
NSString *colourId = nil;
for (NSDictionary *dict in yourArray) {
    if ([dict[@"day_id"] isEqualToString:@"2011-05-06 00:00:00 +0000"]) {
        colourId = dict[@"colour_id"];
        break;
    }
}
NSLog(@"Colour is %@", colourId);
```